# In what language was this following scripture written? What does it mean?

Tags: language-identification

[image]

I was having a chat with someone and I was wondering whether this text (that seems to regard the White Ship incident) were written in some form of English, or possibly in Latin or French.

Sorry for the ignorance, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

This is indeed Latin, and it does seem to to depict the White Ship. It seems to be a genealogy of sorts too. I'm still working on the transcription:

> Henrici nati pelago pereunt adaquanti  *"The sons of Henry perish in the water-bringing sea"*
>
> Filia que remanet imperiale tenet  *"His daughter who remains holds the imperial"*

Below Henry:

> Henricus Rex filius conquestoris genuit  *"King Henry, son of the Conqueror, sired:
>
> ---
>
> Willelmum  *"William"*
>
> qui periit  *"who perished"*
>
> in mari  *"at sea"*
>
> ---
>
> Ricardum  *"Richard"*
>
> qui periit  *"who perished"*
>
> in mari  *"at sea"*
>
> ---
>
> *[centre]* matildem Imperatricem  *"Empress Matildis"*
>
> matrem  *"mother"*
>
> *[left]* Ricardi filii imperatricis qui abiit  *"of Richard, son of the Empress, who went away"*
>
> matrem  *"mother"*
>
> *[right]* Regis Henrici secundi  *"of King Henry the Second"*
>
> ---
>
> Henric. primus regn. xxxv ann. iii mensibus et iacet Rading  *"Henry the First reigned 35 years and 3 months and lies at Reading"*